# Recording time stamp without violating the user input

Tags: php, timestamp, user-agent

Im trying get a timestamp for a reason in website, but according to the way i have coded right now the timestamp prints inside the user inputs area, the current code is as follows

```
$message['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].' Timestamp : ' . $orgtimestamp;
$sql = 'INSERT INTO imp_table (message) VALUES("'.mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($message)).'");';
echo(mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($message)))."\n";
```

the output is like this

```
a:1:{s:15:\"HTTP_USER_AGENT\";s:106:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0 Timestamp : 2014-09-15 09:37:58am\";}
```

So can anybody help me to get a output where timestamp appears like i have shown below

```
a:1: Timestamp : 2014-09-15 09:37:58am :{s:15:\"HTTP_USER_AGENT\";s:106:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0 \";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a:1: Timestamp : 2014-09-15 09:37:58am :{s:15:\"HTTP_USER_AGENT\";s:106:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0 \";}
```

That is not proper serialized string.

```
$message['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$message['Timestamp'] = $orgtimestamp;
echo(mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($message)))."\n";
```

Code above first make array and then serialize it so it should look like:

```
a:2{a:1{s:15:\"HTTP_USER_AGENT\";s:106:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"},{a:1{s:9:\"Timestamp\";s:21:\"2014-09-15 09:37:58am\"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$message['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'Timestamp : '.$orgtimestamp.' '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Comment: i have tried that it doesnt make any difference.. its still inside the curly braces(or the user intputs)